# Parse Server Query to find keywords under username

Tags: swift, parse-server

I'm stuck at attempting to query all the rows in a class "posts" that, first belong to current user, then have "fish" in the column "type" in the same class "posts".

I can successfully get all posts that belong to current user with:

```
let posts = PFQuery(className: "posts")
    posts.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    posts.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (count:Int32, error:NSError?) in
        if error == nil {
            header.posts.text = "\(count)"
        }
```

I've tried simply adding another whereKey  under the first whereKey using

```
posts.whereKey("fish", equalTo: "fish")
```

but this didn't work. Any ideas on what I need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In parse you can add as many conditions as you want. From your code i think the problem is with your second where key. In your second where key you are trying to find all the fishes under the **fish** column and in your question you wrote that you want to find all the fishes under the **type** column so please change this

```
posts.whereKey("fish", equalTo: "fish")
```

To this:

```
posts.whereKey("type", equalTo: "fish")
```